# Update data with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller

Hey i am having a big trouble updating  data in my client side REST application.

I made a Web API controller.

```
    // PUT: api/Contacts/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutContact(Contact contact, int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != contact.ContactId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _contactService.Update(contact);

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

And also client side service method:

```
    public async Task<T> PutData<T>(T data, int dataId)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await this._client.PutAsJsonAsync(_serviceUrl + "/" + dataId, data);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
    }
```

Service URL shows in debug mode that i goes to endpoint:
http://localhost:21855/api/Contacts/8

But it does not even go to breakpoint when i debug my server controller PutContact method.

What i am doint wrong? I need to update the data but i cant, because my client-side application won't even go to servers breakpoint on debug mode!!!
It gives me an error response 405 : Method not allowed

Comment: Can you include code to show how routing is configured in your service? I.E. the calls to config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(), assuming you're using convention based routing and not attribute based routing.

Comment: Also what status code is returned in your response? Is there any exception?

Comment: It gives me an error response 405 : Method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two different body parameters in the same method.

What you need to do is to set the `id` parameter to come from the URI and the `Contact` parameter from the body, like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutContact([FromBody]Contact contact, [FromUri]int id)
{
    // method code
}
```

BTW, I suppose you have a GET method in your controller which looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetContact(int id)
{
    // method code
    return Contact; // pseudo-code
}
```

The error you getting comes from the fact that the system is not really calling your PUT method but the GET one (the system is ignoring the `Contact` parameter for the reason I expressed before): calling a GET method with a PUT verb results in a `405 Method Not Allowed` exception.

Comment: @anduplats mark this answer as correct if it helped you :)